# How to hide Redirect Path and link preview from facebook debugger

Tags: javascript, redirect

I used to redirect my affiliate marketing link for sharing in Facebook pages nd groups. I want my sharing domain redirect path should be hidden from facebook debugger and also my link preview.
Here is the example what exactly i want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqRRH.png

Here is the javascript that i am using but this is not working what i want:

```js
 <link rel="canonical" href="*">

<html>
<body>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=*l" />

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=*" />

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=*" />

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=*" />

script type="text/javascript">
    // Javascript URL redirection
    window.location.replace("*");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```